# Attachment is not working when the file name has ' in it in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a page where I have the option for attaching files. When the files have single quotes in their names is attached, I get an error. This is how I tried:

```
$id = intval(mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_REQUEST["id"]));
        $upload_directory = "uploads/attachments/";
        $result = file_upload("attachment", "../".$upload_directory);
        if($result[status] == true) {
            $query = "insert into `attachments` 
            (
                `id`, 
                `file_name`, 
                `file_extension`, 
                `file_size`, 
                `uploaded_file_name`, 
                `uploaded_file_path`
            ) 
            values 
            (
                '$id', 
                '".$result[file_name]."', 
                '".$result[file_extension]."', 
                '".$result[file_size]."', 
                '".$result[uploaded_file_name]."', 
                '".$upload_directory.$result[uploaded_file_name]."'
            )";
```

This is the error I got:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '2016.xlsx'
                'xlsx',
                '7988',
                '1466056157029.xlsx',
                'upload' at line 15
```

I know this is the place where the problem is: '".$result[file_name]."'. The problem is because of the single quote I've used. What is the change I should do? What should I add?

Comment: learn about prepared statements

Comment: you're missing 'recorded_by' and 'recorded_datetime' in the fields-list of insert-statement.

Comment: "I get an error" - next time post that error. They're there for a reason - to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @Jeff I've added that error now. Check it out.

Comment: have you added the missing field-names yet? is 'id' and 'file_size' field really a string/varchar?

Comment: @Jeff Both are varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add single quotes. You are using `'` in filename so use `addslashes()` and when fetching use `stripslashes()`. OR remove `'` from filename.
 See below code

```
$query = "insert into `attachments` 
        (
            `id`, 
            `file_name`, 
            `file_extension`, 
            `file_size`, 
            `uploaded_file_name`, 
            `uploaded_file_path`
        ) 
        values 
        (
            '$id', 
            '".addslashes($result['file_name'])."', 
            '".$result['file_extension']."', 
            '".$result['file_size']."', 
            '".$result['uploaded_file_name']."', 
            '".$upload_directory.$result['uploaded_file_name']."'
        )";
```

Comment: can you please post here result of echo $query;

Comment: insert into `attachments` 
   (
    `id`, 
    `file_name`, 
    `file_extension`, 
    `file_size`, 
    `uploaded_file_name`, 
    `uploaded_file_path`, 
    `recorded_by`, 
    `recorded_datetime`
   ) 
   values 
   (
    '19', 
    'duddosai-notes'2016.xlsx', 
    'xlsx', 
    '7988', 
    '1466057906111.xlsx', 
    'uploads/attachments/1466057906111.xlsx', 
    '46', 
    '2016-06-16 11:48:26'
   )

Comment: see here  'duddosai-notes'2016.xlsx' an extra `'` is here in your file name

Comment: Ya I know that. Now, the file name should get stored along with that quote. If I put like this: 'duddosai-notes''2016.xlsx', it's working properly. So, in order to do that, what should I change in my variable: '".$result['file_name']."'? Or, is there another way to do that?

Comment: check updatd answer. Use addslashes

Comment: This is what I want. Thanks a lot dude.

Comment: Or better yet, use prepared statements so you can worry less about SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Number of arguments are mismatched in your insert query.
Use single quote,

```
 ex: '".$result['file_name']."'
```